# Get a list of all checked values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of radio boxes on my HTML page. Somewhat like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="19" class="custom" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="19" class="custom" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="19" class="custom" value="3"/>

<input type="radio" name="20" class="custom" value="4"/>
<input type="radio" name="20" class="custom" value="5"/>
<input type="radio" name="20" class="custom" value="6"/>

<input type="radio" name="21" class="custom" value="7"/>
<input type="radio" name="21" class="custom" value="8"/>
<input type="radio" name="21" class="custom" value="9"/>
```

After selecting all radio boxes, the user hits a button. Using Javascript or Jquery, how can I create an array object that holds the values of all checked boxes?

I have an array (`questionsArray`) that holds the `name` values for the radio box sets.

I tried doing this:

```
for (var i=0; i<questionsArray.length; i++)
{
    document.write(document.getElementsByName(questionsArray[i])[0].value + "<br/>");
}
```

Not only does this throw an exception `cannot access value of undefined`, it is not adding them to an array either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you should check http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will put the value of the `value` attribute for each selected radio button into the `arr` Array:

```
var arr = [];
$(".custom:checked").each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$('#buttonId').click( function() {
    var result = '';
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        result += ',' + $(this).val();
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#my-button-id' ).click( function() {
    var tmp = '';
    $( '.custom:checked' ).each( function() {
        // Do what you want...
        tmp += ' ' + $( this ).val();
    });
    alert( tmp );
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the awfully elementary question, but would that code go into a function that is mapped to the final button's `onclick`?