# jQuery get all checked variables from checkboxes

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a list of all checked values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384291/get-a-list-of-all-checked-values)

I have a form with a series of checkboxes all, none or various of which can be checked.

```
 <p><label for="available_lengths">Rail Length:</label></p>
 <p>
  <ul>    
   <li><label for="id_available_lengths_0"><input name="available_lengths" value="132" id="id_available_lengths_0" type="checkbox" class="can_update_lengths" /> 132</label></li>
   <li><label for="id_available_lengths_1"><input name="available_lengths" value="168" id="id_available_lengths_1" type="checkbox" class="can_update_lengths" /> 168</label></li>
   <li><label for="id_available_lengths_2"><input name="available_lengths" value="208" id="id_available_lengths_2" type="checkbox" class="can_update_lengths" /> 208</label></li>
   <li><label for="id_available_lengths_3"><input name="available_lengths" value="240" id="id_available_lengths_3" type="checkbox" class="can_update_lengths" /> 240</label></li>
  </ul>
 </p>
```

How do I loop through these and assign a variable the `.val()` of each?

Comment: " assign them their own variables" means what?

Comment: What do you mean their own variables?  why not just give them different names?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.each` to iterate over the Checkbox elements

```
var checkboxValues = [];

$('ul input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
     checkboxValues.push(this.value);
});

console.log(checkboxValues );
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/kVw6S/)**